# Retrieve results in PostgreSQL stored procedure allowing query parallelism

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to execute an SQL query and process its results inside a stored procedure without preventing query parallelism.
Since I don't want to prevent query parallelism, cursors can't be used, and I would like to avoid creating a temporal table.

Which is the best way to execute the query, retrieve all results in memory, and process its results inside the stored procedure?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a PostgreSQL function or procedure.

Comment: This is because the only way to retrieve results is using cursors?
DYT that using   `EXECUTE SELECT INTO ARRAY_AGG(t.*) INTO result_records` or temporal tables should work? Or am I missing more implications about stored procedures?

Comment: Your use case is not entirely clear to me. You *"don't want to prevent query parallelism"*. OK. What query, what parallelism? Maybe this burns down to a queueing problem.